# How do I refresh data after writing to DB?

Tags: angularjs

I am relatively new to AngularJS and have done many training courses and searching forums and need some guidance on how to solve what I think is a relatively simple problem.

**Background**
I have an MVC App using entity framework code first for backend with sql server db.

On the client side I have serving up the initial Angular View as a .cshtml view via an MVC controller and then using Angular for all the client side partial views and communicating back to the server via Api calls.

**Problem**
I can successfully read data from the database and also save data back to the database.  However when I save data back to the database I have to refresh the page to see the data.

I have solved the problem by updating the in-memory objects and I let Angular handle all the binding.

However this does not seem to be a very good architecture as other users could be adding data to the database and I would never see the entries unless I did a page refresh.

What I am looking for is the best method for getting the data to refresh.

**Service**

```
appMainModule.factory('cmOrgChartService', function ($http,$q) {
return {

    getList: function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('api/orgchart/list').success(deferred.resolve).error(deferred.reject);
        return deferred.promise;

    },
    save: function (orgChart) {
        $http.post('api/orgchart/saveOrgChart', orgChart);
    },
    saveList: function (list) {
        $http.post('api/orgchart/saveOrgCharts', list);
    },
    delete: function (list) {
        $http.post('api/orgchart/deleteOrgChart', list);
    },
};

});
```

**Controller**

```
appMainModule.controller("cmOrgChartController", ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$route', 'cmOrgChartService', function ($scope, $http, $location, $route, cmOrgChartService) {

$scope.orgChartModel = new window.Mojito.OrgChartModel();

$scope.viewList = [];
$scope.editList = [];

$scope.getList = function () {
    cmOrgChartService.getList().then(function (result) {
        $scope.viewList = (result !== null) ? result : {};
    }, function (reason) {
        console.log('Error', reason);
    });
};

$scope.getList();

$scope.edit = function (orgChart) {
    $scope.editMode = true;

    if (orgChart == null) {
        $scope.editList = $scope.viewList;
    } else {
        $scope.editList.push(orgChart);
    }
};

$scope.save = function () {
    if ($scope.editList.length == 1) {
        $scope.orgChartModel = $scope.editList[0];
        cmOrgChartService.save($scope.orgChartModel);
    } else {
        cmOrgChartService.saveList($scope.editList);
    }

    $scope.editList = [];
    $scope.editMode = false;
};

$scope.delete = function (orgChart) {
    cmOrgChartService.delete(orgChart);

    var index = $scope.viewList.indexOf(orgChart);
    $scope.viewList.splice(index, 1);
    $scope.editMode = false;
};

$scope.init = false; 
}]);
```

Comment: You're asking how to refresh your page if *other* people change the data? E.g., a push mechanism?

Comment: You talking about websockets over here.

Comment: I know how to push a new record into my angular object so once I save it shows on page without having to go back to server.  What I am wondering is how do I get the scope object that is populated by the service to refresh.    So if another user added a record whilst i was adding it would show a complete fresh list from the server that included the record i added and any records added by other people